# I am getting the following error "Attempted to access para(2); index out of bounds because numel(para)=1"

Tags: matlab

The most interesting aspect of the problem is that it is not always that I get the error on running the code (I get it 3 out of 5 times). The exact error message is given below

" Attempted to access para(2); index out of bounds because numel(para)=1.

Error in sofunc2 (line 6)
         r2 = para(2)

Error in sosmc_sch1_c2 (line 55)
         obj_value(i)=sofunc2(current_position{:,i}); "

The code is given below

```
tic
clear all
close all
clc
% Initializing variables
S=10;         % no of swarm particles
d=3;           % dimension of swarm particles
c1=2;          % self confidence parameter
c2=1;          % swarm confidence parameter
C=1;           % constriction factor 
LB=[0 0 0];    %lower bounds of variables
UB=[2 2 2];  %upper bounds of variables
wmax=0.9;         % maximum inertia weight
wmin=0.4;         % minimum inertia weight
Xmax=1;       % maximum position
iter=1;        % initial iteration
R1=rand();
R2=rand();
tolerance=1;
Maxiter=40;   % maximum number of iteration
maxrun=5;
dt=1;
particle_best=cell(1,S);
particle_best_value=ones(1,S)*1E10;
global_best_value=1E10;
global_best=zeros(1,d);
obj_value=zeros(1,S);        % Objective function value of particles
%%%%%%%%
current_position=cell(1,S);    % particle position
velocity=cell(1,S);           % particle velocity
dummy=zeros(1,length(d));     % dummy list

% Initialize particle position and velocity
for run=1:maxrun
run
for i=1:S
    for j=1:d
        dummy(j)=round(LB(j)+rand()*(UB(j)-LB(j)));
    end
    current_position{i}=dummy;
    velocity{i}=current_position{i}/dt;   
end
while iter <= Maxiter && tolerance > 0.01

     for i=1:S   
         for j=1:d
              if current_position{i}<LB(j)               %%handling boundary conditions
                 current_position{i}=LB(j);
          elseif current_position{i}>UB(j)
             current_position{i}=UB(j);
              end 
         end
     end 
     for i=1:S
         obj_value(i)=sofunc2(current_position{:,i});
     end
     for i=1:S
        if obj_value(i) < particle_best_value(i)           % finding best local
            particle_best{i}= current_position{i};
            particle_best_value(i)=obj_value(i);
        end
     end
      [fmin,index]=min(obj_value); % finding out the best particle
      ffmin(iter,run)=fmin; % storing best fitness
      ffite(run)=iter; % storing iteration count

        if  min(obj_value)< global_best_value                           % finding best global
            global_best=current_position{obj_value==min(obj_value)};          % updating gbest and best fitness
            global_best_value=min(obj_value);
            fmin0=global_best_value;
        end
        for i=1:S
        w=wmax-((wmax-wmin)/Maxiter)*iter;
        velocity{i}=C*(w*velocity{i}+c1*R1*(particle_best{i}-current_position{i})+c2*R2*(global_best-current_position{i}));
        current_position{i}=current_position{i}+velocity{i};
        end
            % calculating tolerance
        if iter>20;
            tolerance=abs(ffmin(iter-20,run)-fmin0)
        end

         % displaying iterative results
        if iter==1
           disp(fprintf('Iteration Best particle Objective fun'));
        end
           disp(fprintf('%8g %8g %8.4f',iter,index,fmin0));
           iter=iter+1;

        subplot(1,2,1);
        plot(current_position{i}(1),'rO')
        xlim([-5*Xmax    5*Xmax])
        ylim([-5*Xmax    5*Xmax])
        title('Particles instant location')
        grid on
        hold on;
        hold off;
        subplot(1,2,2);
        plot(iter,global_best_value,'bO')
        grid on
        hold on
        xlim([0 Maxiter]);
        title('Best Particle value histogram');
        xlabel('iteration no')
        ylabel('global best value')
%         pause(0.05)
%         disp(['BEST PARTICLE VALUE >> ' num2str(global_best_value)])
end
        % pso algorithm-----------------------------------------------------end
        global_best;
        fvalue=10*(global_best(1)-1)^2+20*(global_best(2)-2)^2+30*(global_best(3)-3)^2;
        fff(run)=fvalue;
        rgbest(run,:)=global_best;
        disp(sprintf('--------------------------------------'));
%         disp(['BEST PARTICLE POSITION >> ' num2str(global_best)])
end

% pso main program------------------------------------------------------end
disp(sprintf('\n'));
disp(sprintf('*********************************************************'));
disp(sprintf('Final Results-----------------------------'));
[bestfun,bestrun]=min(fff)
best_variables=rgbest(bestrun,:)
disp(sprintf('*********************************************************'));
toc
% PSO convergence characteristic
plot(ffmin(1:ffite(bestrun),bestrun),'-k');
xlabel('Iteration');
ylabel('Fitness function value');
title('PSO convergence characteristic')
%##########################################################################


function F = sofunc2(para)
         % Track the output of optsim to a signal of 1

         % Variables a1 and a2 are shared with RUNTRACKLSQ
         c2 = para(1)
         r2 = para(2)
         W2 = para(3)

         disp(sprintf('The value of parameters c2= %3.0f, r2= %3.0f, W2= %3.0f', para(1),para(2),para(3))); 
         % Compute function value
         simopt = simset('solver','ode1','SrcWorkspace','current','DstWorkspace','current');  % Initialize sim options
         [tout,xout,yout] = sim('sosmc_c2',[0 200],simopt);
%         e=yout-1 ;  % compute the error 
%         sys_overshoot=max(yout)-2 % compute the overshoot
    if para(1)<0 || para(1)>5
       penalty=500;
    elseif para(2)<0 || para(2)>5
        penalty=500;
    elseif para(3)<0 || para(3)>5
        penalty=500;
    else
        penalty=0;
    end 

      A=5; %B=1;C=5;
      F=int_abs_error*A+penalty 

    end
```

The code has another part which involves a simulink block named 'sosmc_c2'. However, there is no issue with that block diagram and runs smoothly with other instances of the same program. I would like to know what exactly is causing the error in this particular case and how should I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the error :-|

```
for i=1:S   
     for j=1:d
          if current_position{i}<LB(j)               %%handling boundary conditions
             current_position{i}=LB(j);
      elseif current_position{i}>UB(j)
         current_position{i}=UB(j);
          end 
     end
 end
```

you are comparing current position which is a 1x3 matrices with LB(j) which is a "one element matrix"!!!!

Comment: But, the current position is a cell. Should I declare LB(j) and UB(j) in the cell format so as to make it compatible?

Comment: Do you think the following approach is ok   `current_position{:,i}<LB(j)`

Comment: That didn't work though. I am still getting the error.

Comment: I think you need: `if current_position{i}(j)<LB(j), current_position{i}(j)=LB(j)`. Basically you need access i-th cell and j-th value.

Comment: @biswajit as current_position{i} is not a cell , it is a 1x3 matrices, as mpaskov stated above you could use current_positio{i}(1) for example to get an element of it and then compare it to LB(j)

Comment: Thank You, mpaskov and daren :). The suggestion helped. Now I don't find the error appearing even after 5 or 6 runs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be calling the function, the wrong parameters:

```
obj_value(i)=sofunc2(current_position{i});
```

instead of `current_position{:,i}`.

As far as I can see `current_position` is a columns vector of cells, not a matrix. I can not run the code fully cause I am missing `sim` and `simset`.

---

**Another error, pointed by 'daren shan'**

Checking the boundary conditions you are comparing cells and vector.

```
for i=1:S   
    for j=1:d
        if current_position{i}(j)<LB(j)
            current_position{i}(j)=LB(j);
        elseif current_position{i}(j)>UB(j)
            current_position{i}(j)=UB(j);
        end 
    end
end
```

What was happening before was that if the whole vector `current_position{i}` is smaller or larger by `LB`/`UB` then the vector is replaced by a single value.

Comment: Tell me how may I help you to run the code in your system so that you may be able to get a good idea of the problem I am facing. Meanwhile, I will try implementing your suggestion and revert to you with the findings.

Comment: mpaskov, I have tried using    obj_value(i)=sofunc2(current_position{i});  but it yielded the same result. It works for 1 or 2 runs and then shows errors during the next 3 runs.

Comment: You mean when `i=3:5`?

Comment: what I meant to say is that most of the times the error shows up. Only rarely does the program run without showing any error. Could be due to the random number generators throwing up some unexpected values (just speculating).

Comment: Well i suggest that you put a break point in `sofunc2` and check that all variables are what you expect when the error occurs.

Comment: where exactly would you want me to place the break point in `sofunc2` ?